# Would it be possible to get MathJax?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The author of [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-are-some-good-simple-examples-that-getting-the-right-result-is-not-enough) tried to use LateX markup, presumably thinking it would work in the same way that it does on Math Stack Exchange and Math Overflow.

Would it be possible to get MathJax for this site as well?

Comment: MathJax would make this site a _lot_ more usable.  (-:

Comment: Of course, only a person in a position to meet this feature request can logically answer this question as it is worded, but we all need to make as much noise about this point as possible. How can you talk about maths education without writing any maths at all? This is a no brainer and if we are to have a chance at making this site viable this is one frustration we can do without.

Comment: I need to learn how to use it in my questions and answers. Where do I find that out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\Huge Yes.
$$

<strike>Our usual policy is to ask sites to demonstrate a need for evidence that they need this feature.  This is the [YAGNI development philosophy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/kiss-and-yagni/).  Some excellent examples of how to demonstrate a need come from [Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/80), [Astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/40/48), and [Amateur Radio](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/64/7).  For this site, that requirement might be a little silly; obviously math educators need to use mathematics!  But on the other hand, it ought to be easy to demonstrate the need.  You've already got a good example as a start.</strike>

Comment: And so now we have it I see on the main site (?)

Comment: @Thomas: Yep.  (The bar for demonstrating the need turned out to be exceptionally low.)

Comment: Nice! That was quick!

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\oplus$ $\ast$

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Jon Ericson, this answer will serve to demonstrate that we have a need for MathJax. We do this by making a list of questions where MathJax is needed/useful. Please feel free to edit the following list.

- [What are some good simple examples that getting the right result is not enough?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-are-some-good-simple-examples-that-getting-the-right-result-is-not-enough)
- [Counterexamples in first year calculus](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13/counterexamples-in-first-year-calculus)

Comment: I posted the second question you listed and wasn't able to pose the question as I wished because of the lack of MathJax. I think that MathJax isn't crucial for this site, but may be occasionally useful.

Comment: @GammaFunction: I think it will be crucial. If we will have questions about how to teach specific concepts, then examples are best done with MathJax.

Comment: I agree fully that this site should be MathJax enabled.